# Excell Cell Drop Down Menu randomly lose data when attaching to an email or uploading to Google docs. How to fix?

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-corruption, cells, dropdownlist

My employer uses an excel spreadsheet with drop-down menus in some of the cells to keep track of student attendance. When I send the doc via email and upload the doc via Google Drive, sometimes a number of the cell dropdown menus lose their data, getting recorded as though I hadn't selected an option. When this happens the cells that don't get recorded are the same in both the email attachment and the uploaded google spreadsheet. What gives and how do I fix it? Yes, I am certain I am saving the doc before uploading or attaching.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This seems like a strange occurance but we would need to see a screenshot of the spreadsheet in order to confirm. Is it a macro enabled workbook? When being edited, is the workbook stored on a shared drive / cloud drive like one-drive or is the workbook shared to other users? Maybe its a sync issue? Are you using data validation dropdowns or form/active X controls? Is the dropdown value selected from the dropdown or typed with keyboard? Possibly if typed in it doesn't actaully match one of the items in the list and defaults to blank.

Comment: You should provide a sample about this problem. How did you create the drop down list? Did the list contain any formulas?